# How to efficiently check and associate existing database entities

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a *Post* domain model (aggregateroot). The *Post* should have *Tags*. Tags must be added when the post is created and can later be changed. I want the tags to work in a Add Existing or Create New way. Where should I place the logic that checks if a tag with that name already exists in the DB?

I'm considering a Domain Repository for tags but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach because tags cannot be created without going through the post creation process.

Post Domain Model:

```
public class Post : Entity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly HashSet<Like> likes;
    private readonly HashSet<Save> saves;
    private readonly HashSet<Comment> comments;
    private readonly HashSet<Tag> tags;
    internal Post(string title, string description, string authorId, string? imageUrl, IEnumerable<Tag> tags)
    {
        this.Validate(title,description,authorId);
        if (imageUrl != null)
        {
            this.ValidateImageUrl(imageUrl);
            this.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
        this.Title = title;
        this.Description = description;
        this.AuthorId = authorId;
        this.UploadDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        this.likes = new HashSet<Like>();
        this.saves = new HashSet<Save>();
        this.comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        this.tags = new HashSet<Tag>(tags);
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string? ImageUrl { get; private set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Like> Likes => likes.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Save> Saves => saves.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Comment> Comments => comments.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Tag> Tags => tags.ToList().AsReadOnly();

    public int TotalLikes => likes.Count;
    public int TotalSaves => saves.Count;
    public int TotalComments => comments.Count;

    public Post AddComment(string content, string userId)
    {
        this.comments.Add(new Comment(content, userId));
        return this;
    }
    public Post AddLike(string userId, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        if (likes.All(l => l.UserId != userId))
        {
            likes.Add(new Like(userId, timestamp));
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Post AddTag(Tag tag)
    {
        if (tags.All(t => t.Id != tag.Id))
        {
            tags.Add(tag);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Post RemoveTag(int tagId)
    {
        if (tags.Any(t => t.Id == tagId))
        {
            tags.RemoveWhere(t => t.Id == tagId);
        }

        return this;
    }
    public Post RemoveTag(Tag tag)
    {
        if (tags.All(t => t.Id != tag.Id))
        {
            tags.Add(tag);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Post AddSave(string userId, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        if (saves.All(s => s.UserId != userId))
        {
            saves.Add(new Save(userId, timestamp));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Post RemoveLike(int likeId)
    {
        if (likes.Any(l => l.Id == likeId))
        {
            likes.RemoveWhere(l => l.Id == likeId);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Post RemoveSave(int saveId)
    {
        if (saves.Any(s => s.Id == saveId))
        {
            saves.RemoveWhere(s => s.Id == saveId);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Post RemoveComment(int commentId)
    {
        if (comments.Any(c => c.Id == commentId))
        {
            comments.RemoveWhere(c => c.Id == commentId);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Post UpdateTitle(string title)
    {
        this.ValidateTitle(title);
        this.Title = title;

        return this;
    }

    public Post UpdateDescription(string description)
    {
        this.ValidateDescription(description);
        this.Description = description;

        return this;
    }

    public Post UpdateImageUrl(string imageUrl)
    {
        this.ValidateImageUrl(imageUrl);
        this.ImageUrl = imageUrl;

        return this;
    }
    private void Validate(string title, string description, string authorId)
    {
        this.ValidateTitle(title);
        this.ValidateDescription(description);
        this.ValidateAuthor(authorId);
    }
    private void ValidateTitle(string title)
        => Guard.ForStringLength<InvalidPostException>(
            title, 
            MinTitleLength, 
            MaxTitleLength, 
            nameof(this.Title));

    private void ValidateDescription(string description)
        => Guard.ForStringLength<InvalidPostException>(
            description, 
            MinDescriptionLength, 
            MaxDescriptionLength, 
            nameof(this.Description));

    private void ValidateImageUrl(string imageUrl)
        => Guard.ForValidUrl<InvalidPostException>(
            imageUrl,
            nameof(this.ImageUrl));

    private void ValidateAuthor(string authorId)
        => Guard.AgainstEmptyString<InvalidPostException>(
            authorId, 
            nameof(this.AuthorId));

}
```

Tag Domain Model:

```
public class Tag : Entity<int>
    {
    private readonly HashSet<Post> posts;
    public Tag(string name)
    {
        this.ValidateName(name);
        this.Name = name;

        this.posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Post> Posts => posts.ToList().AsReadOnly();

    public int TotalPosts => posts.Count;

    private void ValidateName(string name)
        => Guard.ForStringLength<InvalidTagException>(
            name, 
            MinTagLength,
            MaxTagLength, 
            nameof(this.Name));
}
```